# Object accessed recursively during construction

Tags: constructor, f#

Consider these four types

```
  type UninitializableType =
    val initialhashcode: int
    new () as newobj =
      { initialhashcode= newobj.GetHashCode () }

  type Parent =
    val mutable initialhashcode: int
    new () as parent =
      { initialhashcode= 0 } then
      do parent.initialhashcode <- parent.GetHashCode ()

  type ChildA =
    inherit Parent
    new () =
      { inherit Parent () }

  type ChildB =
    inherit Parent
    new () =
      { inherit Parent () }
    override child.GetHashCode () = 666
```

All four types are well-defined in the sense that they compile. However, some of these types cannot be initialized.

The first one, `UninitializableType`, is a simplified example of what I would like to do. I use `newobj` inside the constructor expression, so it is not that great a surprise that the constructor fails at run-time.

The second one, `Parent`, is a work-around. It is almost the same as `UninitializableType`, but it has a workable constructor, such that I can create 'Parent' objects. So far, so good.

The third one, `ChildA`, also works. It seems innocent, but the fact that it does not fail kind of tripped me up once I got futher (see below).

The last one, `ChildB`, is the evil one. Despite, at first glance, it looks quite similar to `ChildA`, its constructor fails. Running `ChildB.GetHashCode ()` is technically accessing the unfinished object.

At the moment I am contemplating how to side-step the issue. Do any of you have an elegant solution at hand already?

Edit:

The question is difficult to answer because I did not tell what my end goal is. (Props to TheQuickBrownFox that it did not prevent him from dishing out two good hints/tricks on the topic).

My goal is to have two types, Parent and Child, each with a default constructor (meaning an instance constructor that does not take any parameters). The type Child should inherit Parent, and for this example let us say that the type Parent inherit System.Object.

I would like to do as much initialization as possible in the implementation of Parent, but still allow Child to furnish some details relevant to the initialization. The idea is that the implementation of Child should be as easy as possible. I guess the implementation of Child can explicitly invoke a secondary Parent constructor with as many parameters as I like — it just feels awkward to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. If what you want is to store the initial hash code, while overriding `GetHashCode()` you could do this:

```
type MyType private (initialHashCode) =
  inherit obj()
  new () = MyType(base.GetHashCode())
  member __.InitialHashCode = initialHashCode
  override __.GetHashCode() = 0

let x = MyType()
x.InitialHashCode // 8628710
x.GetHashCode() // 0
```

Comment: Thank you. I see two good tricks here. One trick is that you use another constructor to get rid of the `mutable` part. The other trick is an explicit `inherit obj()` that allows `base.GetHashCode()`.
[ I haven't marked this as an answer yet; I will just leave it open for a while longer to see if there are even better answers out there ]